# XCode 7 Beta 3 - Array extension

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode7-beta3

Old version of code before XCode 7 Beta 3:

```
extension Array {
    func filterByIndex<S: SequenceType where S.Generator.Element == Int>(indices: S) -> [T] {
        return Array(PermutationGenerator(elements: self, indices: indices))
    }

    func find(includedElement: T -> Bool) -> Int? {
        for (idx, element) in self.enumerate() {
            if includedElement(element) {
                return idx
            }
        }
        return nil
    }

}
```

New version of code after XCode 7 Beta 3:

```
extension Array {
    func filterByIndex<S: SequenceType where S.Generator.Element == Int>(indices: S) -> [Element] {
        return Array(PermutationGenerator(elements: self, indices: indices))
    }

    func find(includedElement: Element -> Bool) -> Int? {
        for (idx, element) in self.enumerate() {
            if includedElement(element) {
                return idx
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

But now the function filterByIndex gives me an error when I write this line:

```
let names = (namesArr as! [String]).filterByIndex(dupes)
```

**'[String]' does not have a member named 'filterByIndex'**

What is changed ?

Comment: I agree with @Arkku, the code seems to work just fine. I guess if you could give an example `namesArr` and `dupes` that might help narrow down the issue (and be sure to include the types for those).

Answer (score 0):

The new version of the code works fine for me with:

```
[ "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four" ].filterByIndex([1, 3])
// result: [ "one", "three" ]
```

I'm assuming the problem you're having is somewhere else. I initially suspected the type of `dupes` (the definition of which is not show) no matching the requirements of the generic function, but in my tests the error message should be different in that case.

Comment: `let dupes = indicesOfUniques(namesArr as! [String])`

`public func indicesOfUniques<T: Hashable>(source: [T]) -> [Int] {
    var seen: Set<T> = []
    return source.indices.filter {
        if seen.contains(source[$0]) {
            return false
        }
        else {
            seen.insert(source[$0])
            return true
        }
    }
}`

I changed T with Element in indicesOfUniques and doesn't working...

Comment: @BogdanBogdanov Did you try the code from my answer? If that works for you, then the question is wrong and the issue is with `dupes` or `namesArr`. To see which, replace each one of them with a manually created array of in turn.